# What causes pods to be slow in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Certain pods on my cluster are extremely slow in almost all aspects. Startup time, network, i/o.

I have minimized the application code in these containers and it seems to have no effect, these are basically minimal containers running a simple webapi with a health check endpoint.

I'm wondering someone can help me figure out what's wrong or debug this.

When I say slow in all aspects I mean a couple things

1. Very slow startup.  I actually have to change my readiness probe initial delay to near 5 minutes.
2. Inside the container running any command is slow.  Running an `apt-get update` takes near 5 minutes, even if the container has been running for hours.
3. Any connections to an RDS database will timeout for at least the first 10 minutes the pod is running, after that it's hit or miss, sometimes normal speed, sometimes we'll start getting connection timeouts again (mainly if the pod hasn't been used/requested for awhile).

On nearly identical pods with same base image the container will start in less than a couple seconds, and running an `apt-get update` will take maybe 3 seconds.  I cannot for the life of me see what is different between the pods that causes some to be 'good pods', and others to be 'bad pods'.

Running any of these images locally they will start in no time (less than a second or so).

### My Environment

**Cluster (AWS)**

- 1 c4.large master
- 3 c4.xlarge nodes
- ~10-20 pods per node
- provisioned with kops using 'standard' settings (I haven't done anything tricky)

**Things I've checked/tried**

- too many pods

  My first thought was maybe i'm running too many pods. I've launched up brand new nodes for this (c4.xlarge) and had this pod the only pod running in the cluster, issue still seen.
- node resources

  Checking every node level metric I could nothing looks out of the ordinary (also tried on several brand new pretty high powered nodes)
- Deployment/Pod Metrics

  I'm happy to show whatever metric anyone can think of here, nothing looks out of the norm.  I have Prometheus running and have looked into every metric I could think to check.  I can't see difference between a 'good' running pod and a 'bad' one.
- cluster itself

  I actually have 2 clusters, both provisioned with kops, this is seen on both clusters (though not always the same applications, which is odd).

Any help here is appreciated

Comment: Are you having this issue with a specific pod/image or just any image? Are you having it with all nodes or only a specific one?

Comment: @whites11 happens with all nodes.  The images in my case have always been based on microsoft/dotnet.  I have tried both of their debian:stretch and debian:jessie images and problems on both.  I recently built my own dotnet image from a ubuntu base, same problem occurs.  I'm unsure if this could be a dotnet core problem or not. (I've only seen it on dotnet images, but 90% of what i run is dotnet images)

Comment: I would try and triage the problem. Try running a very simple image, such as nginx:latest, with the most simple settings possible and check if you still have the problem. Since your slowness is on all nodes, I reckon it can be either an external problem (related to the load balancer maybe) or the image you are using.

Comment: Do you have any news?

Comment: @whites11 yes it was a foolish mistake by me that took forever to figure out.  I hadn't noticed or realized that kubernetes was able to throttle the cpu to a pod, i for some reason had the impression it was like the memory resource and it just killed the pod if it was using too many cycles.  Had previously looked at graphs of CPU usage and set the limits to what i thought were reasonable.  The pods apparently needed a bit more juice in order to start-up in a reasonable amount of time.  Once startup is over though they're able to run fine with limited CPU..i should have thought of it earlier :(

Comment: It sounds like whatever you're doing at startup should be part of an InitContainer, not the final running pod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely happening either due to the configuration of Resource Limits that are too constrained or by the lack of configuration Resource Requests which is allowing pods to be provisioned on nodes which do not have the necessary requirements to run their workloads.

You can resolve this by defining proper [resource requests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#resource-requests-and-limits-of-pod-and-container) for each of your applications that are deployed to Kubernetes. In a nutshell, you can control limits and requests for shares of [CPU time](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#cpu-units), bytes of memory, and Linux [Hugepages](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-hugepages/scheduling-hugepages/).